# df.set_index=("Neighbourhood",inplace=True) giving me SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, methods

All of my previous code runs well.

It is only when I try to set the index to a particular column as the code below shows, that I run into an error.

Honestly - this same method has worked before and I have not been able to find any other method to do the same thing.

`df.set_index=("Neighbourhood",inplace=True)`
​

Error message:

File "", line 1
    df.set_index=("Neighbourhood",inplace=True)
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_index` is a function, you need to call it.

try `df.set_index("Neighbourhood",inplace=True)` (without the `=`)